# NSPredicate with Regex to match International set of alphabetic characters

Tags: regex, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am trying to validate a string that represents a place name. I am matching a simple character set like this

```
NSString *regexName = @"[a-zA-Z][., a-zA-Z\\t\\-]*"
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regexName];
```

I would like to know simple regular expression to use to match a broader international character set (principally western characters). I could just enumerate every character I can think of inside the regular expression, but I imagine there is another way. I'm looking for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

`NSRegularExpression` is based on ICU regular expressions, and in their [docs](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp), quite a few options are listed.

The one you are looking for is the Letter property, which is encoded as `\p{Letter}` (or for short, `\p{L}`).

Here is some code for anyone who wants to see it in practice:

```
NSArray *strings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           @"Joe",
                           @"Chloë",
                           @"Søren",
                           @"Renée",
                           @"Se7en",
                           @"Zürich",
                           @"Genève",
                           @"Tromsø",
                           @"Jane",
                           nil];

NSString *regexName = @"\\p{Letter}[., \\p{Letter}\\t\\-]*";

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regexName];

NSArray *filteredArray = [strings filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

It matches all the names with letters, but not the string "Se7en".

The question mentioned Western characters, but it would be nice with examples from languages that use other alphabets, too.